# 1String attaches itself on the end of another C++

Tags: c++, string

I need to write a function that returns "1"   if there are 3 or more similar letters in a row in two strings.

The function I wrote returns "1" no matter what.

I tried to print out which letters it finds similar, and found out that the compiler thinks that after the first should end, it instead matches the second string.
If I try to print out str1, the output is "qwe".
But if I print str1[4], the output is "u"

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int Similar(char* str1, char* str2) {
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(str1) + strlen(str2); i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < strlen(str1) + strlen(str2); j++) {
      if ((str1[i] == str2[j]) && (str1[i + 1] == str2[j + 1]) &&
          (str1[i + 2] == str2[j + 2])) {
        cout << str1[i] << " <1  2>" << str2[j]
             << endl;  // this is just for checking
        cout << str1[i + 1] << " <1  2>" << str2[j + 1]
             << endl;  // this is just for checking
        cout << str1[i + 2] << " <1  2>" << str2[j + 2]
             << endl;  // this is just for checking
        cout << i << " <1  2>" << j << endl;  // this is just for checking
        return 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  int size = 256;
  char str1[size] = {"qwe"}, str2[size] = {"uilo"};
  cout << Similar(str1, str2) << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
u<1   2>u

i<1   2>l

l<1   2>l

4<1   2>0

1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are mixing C and C++,which is a bad thing. Make a choice. If you choose C++, then you should use `std::string` instead of `char*`, and use C++ header files (`cstdio`, `string` instead of `stdio.h`, `string.h`). But your code looks more like C (with the exception of streams).

Comment: Variable length arrays are an extension

Comment: The character string "qwe" has a length of 3 and the valid indexes are 0-2. You are accessing indexes way past the end of the string. Same thing with "uilo" (length 4, indexes 0-3). You need to rethink those `for` loops and also what happens when you do `+1` and `+2` with the indexes. Throw this away and start again.